# SQL query to find DDL script for a table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following script to generate DDL script for the table:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE','TRADE','dev_schema') from dual;
```

OUTPUT:

```
  CREATE TABLE "BCN_QA"."EXM_MESSAGE" 
   (    "MESSAGE_PK" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "XML_MESSAGE" "SYS"."XMLTYPE" , 
    "MESSAGE_TYPE" VARCHAR2(30), 
    "ERROR_CODE" VARCHAR2(1000), 
    "ERROR_DESCRIPTION" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "MESSAGE_CREATION_DATE" VARCHAR2(14), 
    "INSTRUMENT_PK" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "SECURITY_CODE" VARCHAR2(36), 
    "ACCOUNT_PK" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "ACCOUNT_NO" VARCHAR2(46), 
    "SENDER_SYSTEM_ID" VARCHAR2(10), 
    "RECIPIENT_COMPONENT" VARCHAR2(3), 
    "REFERENCE_NUMBER" VARCHAR2(35), 
    "ERROR_NUMBER" NUMBER(4,0), 
    "REMARKS" VARCHAR2(400), 
    "STATUS" VARCHAR2(6), 
    "ACTION_TAKEN" VARCHAR2(10), 
    "USER_COMMENT" VARCHAR2(200), 
    "USER_COMMENT_ENTERY_BY" VARCHAR2(20), 
    "CANCEL_PK" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "GROUP_PK" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "DATA_SOURCE" VARCHAR2(20), 
    "APP_REGI_DATE" DATE, 
    "APP_UPD_DATE" DATE, 
    "CREATED_BY" VARCHAR2(20), 
    "CREATION_DATE" DATE, 
    "UPDATED_BY" VARCHAR2(20), 
    "UPDATE_DATE" DATE, 
    "SENDER_REFERENCE_NO" VARCHAR2(20), 
    "SENDER_BIC" VARCHAR2(15), 
    "NACK_OUT_FLAG" CHAR(1), 
    "NACK_ELIGIBLE_FLAG" CHAR(1), 
    "VALUE_DATE" DATE, 
    "QUALIFIER_STATUS" VARCHAR2(4), 
    "MESSAGE_STATUS" VARCHAR2(6), 
    "ORIGINAL_REF_NO" VARCHAR2(35), 
    "LOCAL_ACCOUNT_NO" VARCHAR2(20), 
    "MSG_PRIORITY" NUMBER(2,0) DEFAULT 4 CONSTRAINT "NN_6055_EXM_MESSAGE" NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "PK_625_EXM_MESSAGE" PRIMARY KEY ("MESSAGE_PK")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 NOLOGGING COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 327680 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "BCN_QA"  ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "FK_1980_EXM_MESSAGE" FOREIGN KEY ("GROUP_PK")
      REFERENCES "BCN_QA"."EXM_GROUP" ("GROUP_PK") ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "FK_1979_EXM_MESSAGE" FOREIGN KEY ("CANCEL_PK")
      REFERENCES "BCN_QA"."EXM_MESSAGE" ("MESSAGE_PK") ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "FK_1976_EXM_MESSAGE" FOREIGN KEY ("ACCOUNT_PK")
      REFERENCES "BCN_QA"."REF_ACCOUNT" ("ACCOUNT_PK") ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "FK_1977_EXM_MESSAGE" FOREIGN KEY ("RECIPIENT_COMPONENT")
      REFERENCES "BCN_QA"."REF_COMPONENT" ("COMPONENT_ID") ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "FK_1975_EXM_MESSAGE" FOREIGN KEY ("INSTRUMENT_PK")
      REFERENCES "BCN_QA"."REF_INSTRUMENT" ("INSTRUMENT_PK") ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "FK_1987_EXM_MESSAGE" FOREIGN KEY ("MESSAGE_TYPE")
      REFERENCES "BCN_QA"."REF_MESSAGE_TYPE" ("MESSAGE_TYPE") ENABLE
   ) PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "BCN_QA" 
 XMLTYPE COLUMN "XML_MESSAGE" STORE AS CLOB (
  TABLESPACE "BCN_QA" ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW CHUNK 8192 PCTVERSION 10
  NOCACHE LOGGING 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)) ;
```

But i want the result like this:

```
  CREATE TABLE "BCN_QA"."EXM_MESSAGE" 
   (    "MESSAGE_PK" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "XML_MESSAGE" "SYS"."XMLTYPE" , 
    "MESSAGE_TYPE" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
    "ERROR_CODE" VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE), 
    "ERROR_DESCRIPTION" VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE), 
    "MESSAGE_CREATION_DATE" VARCHAR2(14 BYTE), 
    "INSTRUMENT_PK" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "SECURITY_CODE" VARCHAR2(36 BYTE), 
    "ACCOUNT_PK" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "ACCOUNT_NO" VARCHAR2(46 BYTE), 
    "SENDER_SYSTEM_ID" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE), 
    "RECIPIENT_COMPONENT" VARCHAR2(3 BYTE), 
    "REFERENCE_NUMBER" VARCHAR2(35 BYTE), 
    "ERROR_NUMBER" NUMBER(4,0), 
    "REMARKS" VARCHAR2(400 BYTE), 
    "STATUS" VARCHAR2(6 BYTE), 
    "ACTION_TAKEN" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE), 
    "USER_COMMENT" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "USER_COMMENT_ENTERY_BY" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "CANCEL_PK" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "GROUP_PK" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "DATA_SOURCE" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "APP_REGI_DATE" DATE, 
    "APP_UPD_DATE" DATE, 
    "CREATED_BY" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "CREATION_DATE" DATE, 
    "UPDATED_BY" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "UPDATE_DATE" DATE, 
    "SENDER_REFERENCE_NO" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "SENDER_BIC" VARCHAR2(15 BYTE), 
    "NACK_OUT_FLAG" CHAR(1 BYTE), 
    "NACK_ELIGIBLE_FLAG" CHAR(1 BYTE), 
    "VALUE_DATE" DATE, 
    "QUALIFIER_STATUS" VARCHAR2(4 BYTE), 
    "MESSAGE_STATUS" VARCHAR2(6 BYTE), 
    "ORIGINAL_REF_NO" VARCHAR2(35 BYTE), 
    "LOCAL_ACCOUNT_NO" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "MSG_PRIORITY" NUMBER(2,0);
```

i.e without storage

Can some one write a query for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to run the following

```
EXECUTE DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM(DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM,'STORAGE','FALSE');
EXECUTE DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM(DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM,'TABLESPACE','FALSE');
EXECUTE DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM(DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM,'SEGMENT_ATTRIBUTES','FALSE');
```

Then you can run

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE','TRADE','dev_schema') from dual;
```

This should give you only the create table statement.

Comment: @saurabhk If this works for you, then you can upvote / accept the answer